# How can I merge two STL maps?

Tags: c++, merge, stl, maps, stdmap

How can I merge two STL maps into one? They both have the same key and value types (`map<string, string>`). If there is an overlap of the keys, I would like to give preference to one of the maps.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Assuming you want to preserve the elements in `mapA`, and merge elements in `mapB` for which there is no key in `mapA`:

```
mapA.insert(mapB.begin(), mapB.end())
```

will do what you want, I think.

(EDIT: If you are using C++17 or newer, consider this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56594603/118150)

Working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

void printIt(std::map<int,int> m) {
    for(std::map<int,int>::iterator it=m.begin();it!=m.end();++it)
        std::cout << it->first<<":"<<it->second<<" ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::map<int,int> foo,bar;
    foo[1] = 11; foo[2] = 12; foo[3] = 13;
    bar[2] = 20; bar[3] = 30; bar[4] = 40;
    printIt(foo);
    printIt(bar);
    foo.insert(bar.begin(),bar.end());
    printIt(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
:!./insert
1:11 2:12 3:13
2:20 3:30 4:40
1:11 2:12 3:13 4:40
```

Comment: I can't see how that doesn't override a duplicate in mapA if the keys match.  If I just say that mapB was my "preferred" map I could use this I think.  That way if it's a duplicate then it the key in mapB would be the one that ultimately ends on in the new map (which is now mapA).  Does that sound correct or am I misunderstanding what insert does when there is a duplicatE?

Comment: Insert will not overwrite existing elements, when there is a clash in the keys, the already existing element takes precedence.

Comment: oh i see. unfortunetly it doesn't build though.  It generates a huge error message

Comment: Sample code added, the basic concept is sound. What sort of error? (Ideally on a simplified code path)

Comment: What is the complexity of this? Is it n log(n), where n is the number of elements in the source map. Or can the complexity be lower (merging two red-black trees)?

Comment: The standard says complexity is n log(n)  (source:cppreference)

Comment: @galinette Not quite, it is O(n log(n+m)) where n is the size of the source range (in this case, indeed the size of the source map), and m is the size of the destination map. (It could be implemented as something like O(n (1 + log(m/(1+n))) + log(m)) in the special case that the source range is sorted by the destination's `value_comp()`, but the standard does not mandate that.)

Answer (score 38):

If you want to copy entries from one map to another, you can use `std::map`'s `insert`:

```
targetMap.insert(sourceMap.begin(), sourceMap.end());
```

But note that `insert` does not update elements if their key is already in targetMap; those items will be left as-is. To overwrite elements, you will have to copy explicitly, e.g.:

```
for(auto& it : sourceMap)
{
    targetMap[it.first] = it.second;
}
```

If you don't mind losing the data in `sourceMap`, another way to achieve a copy-and-overwrite is to `insert` the target into the source and `std::swap` the results:

```
sourceMap.insert(targetMap.begin(), targetMap.end());
std::swap(sourceMap, targetMap);
```

After swapping, `sourceMap` will contain `targetMap`'s old data, and `targetMap` will be a merge of the two maps, with preference for `sourceMap`'s entries.

Answer (score 25):

### C++17

As mentioned in [John Perry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49584930/2675154), since [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) provides a [`merge()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/merge) member function. The `merge()` function produces the same result for the target map as [jkerian's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639797/2675154) based on using [`insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert), as you can see from the following example, which I borrowed from jkerian. I just updated the code with some [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) and C++17 features (such as [`using` type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias), [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) with [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding), and [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)):

```
using mymap = std::map<int, int>;

void printIt(const mymap& m) {
    for (auto const &[k, v] : m)
        std::cout << k << ":" << v << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    mymap foo{ {1, 11}, {2, 12}, {3, 13} };
    mymap bar{ {2, 20}, {3, 30}, {4, 40} };
    printIt(foo);
    printIt(bar);
    foo.merge(bar);
    printIt(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 1:11 2:12 3:13
>   2:20 3:30 4:40
>   1:11 2:12 3:13 4:40

As you can see, `merge()` also gives priority to the target map `foo` when keys overlap. If you want to have it the other way round, then you have to call `bar.merge(foo);`.

However, there is a difference between using `insert()` and `merge()` regarding what happens to the source map. The `insert()` functions adds new entries to the target map, while `merge()` moves entries over from the source map. This means for the example above, that `insert()` does not alter `bar`, but `merge()` removes `4:40` from `bar`, so that only `2:20` and `3:30` remain in `bar`.

Note: I reused the example from jkerian which uses `map<int, int>` for the sake of brevity, but `merge()` also works for your `map<string, string>`.

[Code on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2dd496f049963631)

Answer (score 19):

Notice that, since C++17, there is a [`merge()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/merge) method for maps.

Answer (score 3):

According to ISO/IEC 14882:2003, section 23.1.2, Table 69, expression a.insert(i,j):

> pre: i,j are not iterators into a. inserts each element from the range
>   [i, j) if and only if there is no element with key equivalent to the
>   key of that element in containers with unique keys;

Since that std::map must follow this restriction, if you'd like to give preference to "values" from one map over another you should insert into it. For example,

```
std::map<int, int> goodKeys;
std::map<int, int> betterKeys;

betterKeys.insert(goodKeys.begin(), goodKeys.end());
```

So if there are any equivalent keys in goodKeys and betterKeys, "values" of the betterKeys will be preserved.